# Visual Studio Navigation Short Cuts

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In the Visual Basic 6.0 IDE, it was possible to navigate to the start of the next (previous) subroutine or function by pressing CTRL + Down Arrow (Up Arrow). This does not work in VS2010.

- Is there another key combination for this?
- Can it (has it) be (been) implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look on the Visual studio keyboard shortcuts released by Microsoft

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/visual-studio-2010-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx